# Why doesn't button do anything when I press it in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I created an "Add New" button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
   style="margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 5px"
   href="{{ route('jobs.create') }}"
>Add New</a>
```

This is my JobsController create method:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('jobs.create');
}
```

This is my jobs.create view:

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'jobs.store']) !!}        
     @include('jobs.fields');
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Jobs.fields are fields.

How come, when I press the "Add New" button, nothing gets displayed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your controller handle `jobs.create` route

Comment: Route::resource('jobs', 'jobController');

Comment: I added bottom. help me

Comment: I want to see your `controller`, not your route